# NPM install fail unless --no-bin-links is used. Why is that? Probably Ubuntu file permissions, still unsure

Tags: 22.04, nodejs, npm, fat32

There's a lot going on with this drive and I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting.  I have a HDD which is partitioned to have 10GB of unallocated space.  I formatted as FAT32 and mounted that space to /mnt/AB67-D2AC.  The drive should have execute permissions based on a steam install on the drive (auto mount options off, mount on startup on). There is a windows install on a separate partition.  I tried:

```
chmod -R 777 ./
chown -R me ./
sudo npm install
```

I know FAT32 doesn't have the normal ubuntu file permissions on it, is that the issue?  Its unsupported by the format?

The problem occurred when using NPM, error below. Sudo npm install did not help.

I tried expanding the drive in gnome-disk-utility but that did not seem to be an option (only shrinking).  npm install ouputs:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /mnt/AB67-D2AC/ticketing/issueTracking/node_modules/.bin/mime
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/mnt/AB67-D2AC/ticketing/issueTracking/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/mnt/AB67-D2AC/ticketing/issueTracking/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/AB67-D2AC/ticketing/issueTracking/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hppc/.npm/_logs/2023-03-29T14_49_56_221Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: FAT32 does not support ANY Ubuntu file permissions. It is not even a FS type that Ubuntu normally understands.

Comment: Did you "try running the command again as root/Administrator" as suggested at the end of error message?

Comment: @David Thanks, I figured it was something like that but I had too many things to look into with no previous experience